# Android - Add Linearlayout above ListView

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android

I would like to add a `LinearLayout` above a `ListView,` so that when you scroll the screen, it scrolls the entire layout. In my `LinearLayout`, I have an AChartEngine `GraphicalView`, which I want above the `ListView`. I added a `ScrollView`, and inside that a `Spinner`, `LinearLayout` `ListView`, but when I run the app, only the `ListView` and the `Spinner` show up. The `LinearLayout` doesn't show up on the screen.

Here is my xml file. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spending_report_cycle_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spending_report_graph"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layou`enter code here`t_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/spending_report_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

When I call the method that returns my graph, I am given a View, which I need to add to the Layout. The only way I know of to do this is to add it to a LinearLayout.

```
    graphLayout = (LinearLayout)view.getViewById(R.id.spending_report_graph);
    graph = PieGraph.getNewInstance(getActivity(), items, items.size());
    graphLayout.addView(graph);
```

Comment: Could you not add those views to the ListView header?

Comment: I tried, but it restricts the height of the LinearLayout to the height of a ListBlock. The LinearLayout's height is larger than the height of a ListBlock.

Comment: are you sure your layout is right ? because scroll view can have only one direct child item.

Comment: Have you tried giving fix height for spending_report_graph? Because there might be case with graphs that it was never created so the wrap_content will set to 0dp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is this you want to achieve ?

[Test Image http://imageshack.com/a/img43/3327/f091.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img43/3327/f091.png)

IF yes, then description is like, Item1 is the spinner, Item 2 on the bottom is the ListView and the black line in between is the View and the extire layout is in the linear layout and it has one child (Scroll View) and only one direct child of scroll view that's Linear layout.

Here's the xml for it. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spending_report_cycle_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/spending_report_graph"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/spending_report_listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### **Here's the edited answer :**

[Test Image http://imageshack.com/a/img809/7741/ti70.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img809/7741/ti70.png)

Here's I am using fragment just to confirm everything was working fine and yes, everything's working perfect.

as you see, there's the fragment I am using, the spinner is at the top, list view on the bottom and after executing the code, here's how the view looks like :

[Test Image 2 http://imageshack.com/a/img713/685/qpbi.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img713/685/qpbi.png)

Here, the view inside two green lines is the fragment. Here's the code for everything:

**First : the yourmainlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spending_report_cycle_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/SomeView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#008080"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_content_1"
                android:name="com.mike.passintents.Fragment1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/SomeView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#008080"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/spending_report_listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="#333333" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Second : The Fragment1**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mike.stackoverflowquestions.R;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);

    }

}
```

**Third: Main Activity**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mike.stackoverflowquestions.R;

public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    String somevalue1 = "Hello";
    String somevalue2 = "World";
    ListView mListView;
    String[] numbers_text = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four",
            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
            "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen" };
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
    Spinner spinner1;
    TextView tV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_view_stack);
        mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String s : numbers_text) {

            mArrayList.add(s);

        }
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spending_report_cycle_spinner);
        tV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spending_report_listview);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mArrayList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,
                mArrayList);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    }

    public void selectFragment(View view) {

        Fragment fr;

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnSayHi)) {

            fr = new Fragment1();

        } else {

            fr = new Fragment1();

        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_content_1, fr);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

I made the edit. Please let me know if this works. Good luck..:)

Comment: Actually, it is similar, but not quite. I want to put a View between the Spinner and the ListView, but programmatically. When I call the method that returns my graph, I get a view, and I need to add that to my Layout. (I have updated my Question with the code for generating the graph). What I want is more similar to this actually: http://imgur.com/g5Er23M

Comment: Did you try using a fragment instead of that view ? If you use the fragment, you can then show your graph in that fragment from your fragment class.

Comment: Yes, I am using a fragment. I put the graph in the fragment, above the ListView, but when I add the graph, the listview doesn't show at all.

Comment: ThankYou! It works just like I wanted. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am glad to help you out  .. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49706/discussion-between-mike20132013-and-franz-danconia)